# Khintchine inequality for the linear combination of sparse Bernoulli random variables

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, probability-inequalities, inequality

Let $\{\epsilon_{n}\}_{n=1}^{N}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $P(\epsilon_{n} = \pm 1) = 1/2$ for $n=1,2, \ldots, N$ i.e. a sequence of Rademacher distribution. Let $0<p<\infty$ and let $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. Then from Khintchine inequality
\begin{equation}
    A_{p} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} |x_{n}|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq \left( E \Big| \sum_{n=1}^{N} \epsilon_{n} x_{n} \Big|^{p} \right)^{1/p} \leq B_{p} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} |x_{n}|^2\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}
for some constants $A_p,B_p>0$  depending only on $p$.

My question is if we choose  $\epsilon_{n}$ from sparse Bernoulli distribution instead of Rademacher distribution i.e.
$$
\epsilon_{n} = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2s} \\
0 & \text{ with probability } 1 - \frac{1}{s}\\
+1 & \text{ with probability } \frac{1}{2s}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the Khintchine inequality will hold or not? Or is it possible to come up with some similar bounds as given by Khinchine inequality for the above distribution?

Comment: Bernoulli refers to when the sample space is $\{0,1\}$; I suppose you meant Rademacher r.v.s. Khintchine's inequality relies on subGaussianity. The first step is to check whether the discrete random variable of yours is subGaussian.